# Why is Context used in this piece of code?

Tags: android

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
```

Here in this code,what does this **Context**  means and what is the purpose of using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) is an abstract Class that is used to access system resources like the network connection, or the file system or a database. In this case I would asume that the context is saved in the Adapter to load Images later in the progress.